# SSH connection refused to Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssl

I am using a windows 10 machine(corporate), firewall is turned off.

I have installed Ubuntu on my VMWare VM and setup openssh-server. I also did: sudo netstat -tupan to see if my ssh daemon is listening, and it does accordingly.

When doing ssh localhost from the VM itself, of course it works, prompts me password and connects successfully.

But when for example I try to use Powershell, Gitbash, WSL or another VM I get connection refused. Also ssh is enabled on firewall on VM as well as port 22.

ifconfig from VM:

[image]

```
So my ip should be: **192.168.11.129** and my username is **john**

When trying to ping 192.168.11.129 from gitbash I get Request timed out
```

So why does my WSL, Gitbash or powershell can't ping my ubuntu on VM ?

Comment: Can you ping the Host from the Guest? Can you ping the Guest from the Host? Can the Guest ping other machines on the same LAN?  Can other machines on the same LAN ping the Guest?

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of the terminal. Always copy the text from the terminal and paste it directly into your question. Then use the format as code button { } to format the pasted text.

Comment: Everyone can ping everyone, I just checked.